# Adding few fields to custom content type problem

Tags: 7, nodes, caching

I've met some strange behavior while manipulating with fields of "sometype" content type. Sometimes after adding few custom fields one by one (and configuring them in few steps), after returning to "Manage fields" new field isn't listed, while Drupal message says Field added. Same with removing fields - Drupal message says that field was removed, but it is still on list.

Does anyone meet similar behavior **and found the reason?** I'm on D7(12) out of the box **without overlay module**.

In db after removing field from content type (using UI) still resides field_my_field and revision_field_my_field. Usually I remove it manually, but it seems weird.

ADDITIONAL INFO

db mysql 5.1.28, PHP 5.3.8, Webserver Apache/2

After x field created (text) I try **immediately** to add y field (text) and I'm getting

Page not found
The requested page "/admin/structure/types/manage/sometype/fields/field_y/field-settings?destinations[0]=admin/structure/types/manage/sometype/fields/field_y&destinations[1]=admin/structure/types/manage/sometype/fields" could not be found.

Comment: Any cache software running outside Drupal ?

Comment: Don't know that, I'm on shared server. I have a lot D6 sites on it, but now I'm thinking of go to D7.

Comment: Any errors in log ? Is error reporting configured correctly for PHP ? What is the PHP version on the server - are you sure it fits the [requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) ?

Comment: http://cleard7.trenerbiznesu.pl/  (U: admin P: stackex) (I'll remove this comment myself after disabling dev site)

Comment: I did a quick tour and saw nothing wrong. Created a field then deleted it. It only disappeared after cron run. I still stand for a cache problem somewhere outside Drupal, as I don't see any other explanation.

Comment: I mentioned that it is about creating multiple fields, not one. So the answer is: "run cron after each field creation"?

Comment: I tried to explain the problem as I could, and the explanation can stand for several fields as well. The test I ran on your site did work, so it's a workaround, but it definitely doesn't solve the underlying problem. And I've reached my limits.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought that there was something like "It is recommended to clear cache after each field modiffication"in Field API. And you can't add countzero field anymore without manual db clearing... That is strange.

Comment: No, normally clearing cache or running drush is only needed for special dev cases. As I said, I'm almost sure some cache is messing things up somewhere.

Comment: It's a little bit amazing, but some of my files were corrupted due upload via mobile weak net. After uploading through fast net all of D7 core files and dependencies it is work as expected. Thank you anyway for help.